# jmeter + Selenium iDE

Tags: selenium, jmeter, selenium-ide

I'm unable to active Redline recording button in SeleniumIDE,I have recorded my steps then clicked on  Redline recording button & run the recorded steps but in this time Redline recording button is showing as inactive & after running the steps again clicked on Redline recording button to save jmx file but it appears that-  "Nothing to Save"

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get this work with using trello.com as the target, I will document steps below.

1 - Setup Options to only record from trello.com
[image]

2 - Start RedLine13 button, Playback, and Save
- I open up trello and add a new card, click on existing card, and close dialog
[image]

3 - Open up in JMeter
[image]

4 - JMX File Output and Running Test

- JMX File that was created - https://www.redline13.com/share/download/31888?path=testplan
- Example Run - https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/31888
- Not a valuable test, but just an example

Comment: Me also able to record the steps & download JMX file for "Trello.com" site but for signing into my project or for gmail sign in couldn't be able to record by following your steps .:)

Comment: Change the includes option to .* so it captures all domains. That said, it will take further work to refine the JMX if you want to capture output from google login and pass it along to the trello login.

Answer (score 1):

That is just a "visual issue" you should hit the JMETER button one time then play the entire test suite on selenium and when the test suite have been completed hit the JMETER button again and a modal windows to save as JMETER sould appear

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix this problem is really easy but unintuitive: simply remove the "http:" header in the url (in the includes options of the JMeter plugin)

Example:

-wrong: https://stackoverflow.com

-rigth: stackoverflow.com

[Img with correct form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTgYB.png)

I hope that this steps helped to solve your